# gnome software application manager : disable automatic request for extensions list

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-shell-extensions

does anyone know if there's a way to disable the automatic request 'feature' in the ubuntu 19.10 software application manager that requests a json list of available extensions from `extensions.gnome.org` every time the application is brought to the foreground ?

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2020-03-06**

*I tested it on Fedora and since it also uses the Gnome desktop, it may also work for your Ubuntu.*

There is a collapsed tab at the top bar, where the ***software source*** option can help you disable the software source, and ***update preferences*** allow you to disable automatic updates and prompts.

---

If your problem is caused by an extension, please uninstall or close it. If you're not sure where to find the portal, consider using the gnome-tweaks tool.

If it is caused by improper program settings, you need to change its configuration. It's a pity that I haven't encountered similar problems. If it really bothers you, it can be solved by uninstalling it.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. no, the problem isn't w/an extension ; it's w/the software manager, which tries to query `extensions.gnome.org` to find out what extensions are available. i want to disable this behaviour, if possible. this is for a virtual environment and there's no route to extensions.gnome.org, nor should there be.

Comment: Got it, I updated my answer, hope it will be useful to you.

Comment: it appears it's not possible, even changing the settings to 'never' notify and 'never' update. i'll just have to advise those who use the vm not ignore it. in any case, thanks much for your help.